# ASP. NET Core free database for Azure

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, azure

I am looking for an option to have a free database on Azure. 
From the [article](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/windows-azure/883/host-aspnet-mvc-azure-without-database) I see that there is an option to have free DB on Azure. But it works for standard ASP.NET MVC. How can I achieve this in ASP.NET Core ?
Or, maybe Azure provides some free/very cheap DB?

Comment: It seems like there are two questions here, one is 'what free databases  are there on Azure?' which would be outside the scope of SO.  The second question is 'How can I connect to an Azure database from ASP.NET Core?'.  I'm certain that there are answers to both of these questions on their respective websites.

Comment: I just searched the internet and found [Entity Framework Core](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/)

Answer (score 1):

there used to be a free SKU for SQL server, but's no longer available. the only free db option you have atm is ClearDB's hosted MySQL (Mercury tier). if you have the correct DB drivers or framework then you can do this easily : https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/data/index.html 
Hope this helps

Comment: I have an error during installing it, says: Your purchase of the application and service ClearDBMySQLDatabase cannot be completed at this time. Please try again later.

Comment: Finally found how to find ClearDB MySQLDB on Azure. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/store-php-create-mysql-database/#CreateForWebSite

Answer (score 0):

Once you have created the free database you can use it for any purpose you desire.

You can get the connection string and add allowed IP addresses through the Azure portal.

Comment: Actually, I do not see free DB on Azure. The cheapest one is SQL server for 4.99$ per mont (I am using FREE plan on azure)

Answer (score 0):

During development I am using SQLLite, which is free and works like a charm. It is perfect for small applications. Using it with Entity Framework however might cause some issues when database changes are introduced later. But once you switch to production you can just use a different database provider.